# CKEditor in a bootstrap tab powered by javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I have an application with CKEditor in a bootstrap tab, the tabs are powered by javascript, when i initialize CKEditor **before** initializing the tabs, the tabs only work in `Chrome`.

i came up with a solution where i initialize CKEditor only when the CKEditor tab are active, but now when i submit the form (all tabs are wrapped in a form) CKEditor does not send it's content with the form.

How can i solve this ?

here is some code:

when i initialize ckeditor before the tabs, the tabs only work in `chrome`.

```
$(function(){
  $('.editor').ckeditor();
});
```

when i initialize ckeditor when it's tab is active it does not send it's content
with the form...

```
$('#ckeditor-tab').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('.editor').ckeditor();
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the textarea below CKEditor isn't being updated. Adding `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.updateElement();` before the form submit and it should work.

See http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#updateElement